# how to run a second SQL query if the first result is null

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I'm going around in circles with this and hope someone can shed some light on how I can run a second query when the first returns a null.

```
select employee, date, workingrule
case when workingrule is null
then 1 else (select employeenumber, bonusrule from employeelist)
end
from employeedetails
```

Basically if the workingrule is blank I wanted to find the employees bonusrule.
Any help of guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thanx

Comment: Your 'Then' Clause contains one value, but the 'else' clause contains two.  Also, the 'else' clause returns more than one row - so filter it with a where clause.

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS you should be able to `select IfNull(workingrule, bonusrule)`

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: unfortunately ifnull is not a recognised built in function name. I'm using a proprietary MySQL...

Comment: Surprising - in that case try `Coalesce()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one works for SQL Server (because using `isnull`, but it's possible to change it to any RDBMS specific query):

```
select
   ed.employee, ed.date,
   isnull(ed.workingrule, el.bonusrule) as [rule]
from employeedetails as ed
    left outer join employeelist as el on el.employeenumber = ed.employeenumber
```

or if you want both (should work for any RDBMS):

```
select
   ed.employee, ed.date,
   ed.workingrule,
   case when ed.workingrule is null then '1' else el.bonusrule end as bonusrule
from employeedetails as ed
    left outer join employeelist as el on el.employeenumber = ed.employeenumber
```

Comment: I tried the second statement and now I'm getting 'conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TP-WORK-FULL' to data type int. Is this caused by the "is null then 1"?

Comment: @Withdalot yep, changed the query. This happened because 1 is int and your bonusrule column is nvarchar.

Comment: @Withdalot are you using SQL Server?

Comment: -unfortunately not, it's a proprietary version of MySQL

Comment: so you can change isnull in first one to ifnull (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I'll stick with your first statement and see how we go in testing. simple is best and tank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  employee, date, Coalesce(workingrule, BonusRule) as Rule 
from 
  employeedetails ed
  left join employeelist el on 
    el.employeenumber = ed.employeenumber
```